# FaceBook like-button callbacks not working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Can anyone tell me why callbacks are not working for the like-button code given below? The code is a standard set up in JavaScript as far as I can see. The first button is initialized, then the API is loaded asynchronously, and callback functions are provided.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit=function(){
    FB.init({
        appId:'',//App ID
        status:false,// check login status
        cookie:true,// enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml:true// parse XFBML
    });
    // Additional initialization code here

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        //alert("user_id1:<?php echo $user_id1; ?>, user_id2:<?php echo $user_id2; ?>");
        /*var data={
            action:"ap_buttons_give_points",
            author_id:<?php echo $author_id; ?>,
            post_id:<?php echo $post_id; ?>,
            type:"like"
        }

        jQuery.post("<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>",data,function(resp){

        });*/
    alert('You just liked the page!');
});

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
        /*var data={
            action:"ap_buttons_take_points",
            author_id:<?php echo $author_id; ?>,
            post_id:<?php echo $post_id; ?>,
            type:"like"
        }

        jQuery.post("<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>",data,function(resp){
            //alert("fb remove:"+resp);
        });*/
    alert('You just unliked the page!');
});
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

Comment: The button is HTML5. The code is:<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>. How are callbacks defined in this case?

Comment: I'm also getting this:FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code seems fine. I kinda had the same problem but only with fb like button, the iframe version.
I don't see the fb button in your example, so I don't know which one you use... So, from my experience, use the standard fb like.

Answer (score 0):

The only time this has occurred to me is when I was using the iframe version of the Like button. I've found that the callback doesn't work at all with that version. If this is the case, you'll want to use the Javascript SDK version found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), either using XFBML or HTML5:

```
<fb:like send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

or

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```